# LUIS pattern feature does not detect my entity

Tags: bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I want to detect an entity from an intent, that might be written in several ways:

AB 123456
AB 123 456
AB123456

AB is an option from a closed list, and the rest should be detected as number(s). As long as there **is a space between AB and the number**, the list item and the number(s) are detected/resolved.

I discovered the pattern feature and hoped this could help out the parser.

Unfortunately, the entity can still not be recognized. I tried to write the pattern in different ways, with no success.

^([A-Za-z]{1,2})([0-9 ]+)$

([a-z]{2})([\d ]+)

[a-z]{2}[\d ]+

Any idea?

Comment: For reference, are you developing your bot with .NET or Node.js SDK?

Comment: With .net, but the problem can be reproduced on the luis portal as well (using train & test)

Answer (score 0):

> *AB is an option from a closed list, and the rest should be detected as number(s). As long as there **is a space between AB and the number**, the list item and the number(s) are detected/resolved.*

If `"AB"` is from a closed list entity, then you should create a simple entity for the numbers and a composite entity to hold the two together. The simple entity would need to be trained with a few utterances, e.g. `"123456"`, `"123 789"`, `"456789"`, `"201731"` and then the model (with the help of a RegExp pattern for your pattern feature, `[\d]{6}`) should be able to handle the rest.

You would employ your list entity and newly created simple entity as children of a composite entity. One that might be something like "Product" or something better than that.

I think you might be thinking that a closed list is Machine learned, but it is not. It is directly matched against utterances, so if your list entity had the following:

```
canonicalForm: "ProductId"
synonyms: "AB", "BA", "AB 123456"
```

And the utterance *`"BA 123456"`* was processed by the model, the LUIS model would recognize `"BA"` as a `"ProductId"` and not recognize `"123456"` at all. By extension, the entire utterance would not be recognized as one `"ProductId"`.

Comment: I already tried that with the composite entity, but with the builtin number and not a simple type. The problem remained the same, the childs got recognized only, if there was space between "AB" and the number. I'm aware that the closed list items are not machine learned (unfortunately). I also tried your suggestion with the simple type, but the result is worse because it detects "AB123456" as the simple type now. Currently I'm preprocessing the user input in .net with the regex and add a space beetween the groups, then send it to luis :(

Comment: Yuck :( You could try using the Authoring API or doing batch training to force it to recognize white space when you select the indicies of your labeled entities (not sure if this works, haven't tried) but it might be for naught depending on the tokenization. You'd also need to add a whitespace to your regexp pattern (which I should have thought of in my initial answer). This white space would go before the numbers...

Comment: The problem only exists when there is **no** whitespace. If I train with "AB123456" I can't label just "AB". I'm only able to select the whole word.

Answer (score 0):

*The problem only exists when there is no whitespace. If I train with "AB123456" I can't label just "AB". I'm only able to select the whole word.*

Luis only analyses the text and help you to get the required endpoints and context for your work. It will not perform programming activity like reading a certain portion of the string and assigned to an entity... at least not yet